# css links header problem

Tags: html, css

I've made a css file with:

```
a:link {font-size: 24px;}
#header {font-size:8pt }
```

My html file contains a div with id="header" and this contains only some links.  I'm trying to make the links in the header to be 8pt and the links in the rest of the document to be 24px.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
a:link {font-size: 24px;}
#header a:link {font-size:8pt }
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try:

```
#header a {font-size: 8pt;}
```

instead of

```
#header {font-size: 8pt;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aqDma/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
a {font-size:24pt}
#header a {font-size:8pt}
```